# how to set width,height of telerik RAD Calendar

Tags: telerik

In my asp.net web site project I want to make rad calendar control smaller programmatically that get rendered by default to the browser(which is quite big for my requirement).I tried setting height and width of the control it doesn't work.How can I fix this?

```
RadCalendar calendar = new RadCalendar();                   
calendar.Width = x;
calendar.Height = y;
Panel1.Controls.Add(calendar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the Telerik Skins actually have a minimum height and width setting for the RadCalendar in order to ensure that the visual styles of the control are not broken. As you can imagine modifying the width and height to arbitrary settings could skew the look and feel of the control quite a bit. What you can do, however, is either modify one of the existing skins or create your own. [This section in their online documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar_appearancecustomskin.html) covers how to change the appearance, and the specific article covers how to create a custom skin.